# Python 2d list average columns

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list of the format `peaks = [[3.56, 7.94, 3.56,... ], [...]]`.

I'm trying to use the following list comprehension to create a list containing the averages of each of the columns of `peaks`. That looks like this,

`[sum(peaks[:,i])/len(peaks) for i in range(len(peaks[0]))]`

As far as I know, this is proper column-slicing and list comprehension syntax, and yet I get this error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are these python lists  or Numpy arrays? Regular lists don't support that kind of indexing.

Comment: If `peaks` is a `List[list]`, then `avgs = [sum(col)/len(col) for col in zip(*peaks)]`. However, I'd strongly recommend using `numpy` for working with multidimensional numerical data.

Comment: Also, `[:, i]` is *not* proper slicing syntax in pure Python.

Comment: Thanks all. I will convert the lists from native Python to numpy. However, further question: what's the preferred method of programmatically creating a numpy array? In my case, I'm populating a python list of lists in a for loop, and then I convert it to numpy after it is finished building (like `np.array([finished list])`). But I get the deprecation warning about ragged nested sequences

Answer (score 0):

First you can transform the row to column in your list, for example:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] to [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Then you can use  [statistics.mean()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

```
>>>import statistics
>>>l=[]
>>>peaks = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>>peak=[*zip(*peaks)]
>>>peak
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>>for i in peak:
>>>    l.append(statistics.mean(i))
>>>l
[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this averaging the rows of the 2d array. I am trying to average the columns

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, I hope it will help :)